# document.getElementById("").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = Not Working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I have these 3 lines of code in an external javascript file

```
function init(){
document.getElementById("upcoming_event").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/fastnet_2013_poster.jpg";
    document.getElementById("club_championship").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/club_championship.png";
    document.getElementById("setMembership").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/join_our_club.png";
}

document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded" , init , false);
```

This code works perfectly on [this site](http://lizzymurphy.hostoi.com/) which i used just to develop a little bit of it with 000webhosting.

But I have now moved my hosting to hosting24 to complete the development of the site. When i load the site through the new host(hosting24) the images are not getting loaded.

I have taken these 3 line of code out and tried them in an `<body onload="init()">` but this dose not load the images either.

I know that both methods above are being called  as i have got them to display a `window.alert("Display")`.

Is there another way of doing this?

(`document.getElementById("upcoming_event").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "images/fastnet_2013_poster.jpg";`) that i could try and use? Or solve my problem.

Comment: Can you link to the new code? Hard to tell why it doesn't work if we can't see it

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: Does your new host have the same directory structure as your old host?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Would an incorrect path result an "image not found" icon appear?

Comment: @Teemu Yes, because you're assigning it an image location that doesn't exist. The image will not be found.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what happens, "image not found" icons appear, or just nothing at all? And the console...

Comment: you have to be logged into see the site but i can send you the code if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing servers should not effect javascript code at all. Only thing that comes to mind is that the URL's for the images sources isn't correct anymore, because of the move.

Comment: All my other images work ok except the three i try and set in the way above

Comment: This might be a base-url issue, or public html directory etc. Anyway, it's related to the path you are giving the images.

Comment: Run the code in console(in dev tools or firebug) and see if he finds the images or returns an error. If it can't find the images, check out the url manually and see what's what.

Answer (score -2):

First you can use jQuery to help you do this in a simpler way like:

```
$('#upcoming_event').find('img')[0].src = "url";
```

or

```
$('#imgid').attr('src', 'xpto.jpg');
```

Secound, the code seems to work... I think the problem may be in the urls of the IMGs. Check if the images are in the correct folder or if the path is right.

Comment: image path is ok if i set it <div id="upcoming_event"><a href=""><img src="images/fastnet_2013_poster.jpg" alt="Next Event"/></a>